# How can I make animation in Python?

Tags: python, animation

I'm trying to create animation about the change of x,y,z coordinates of one quantum bit with quantum calculation called X-gate. Here are the codes that I wrote.

```
#length means number of phase here
length = 10
# theta, pi are variable we need to calculate x,y,z in each phase
# and I get these values from users.
xgate_theta = np.linspace(theta,theta+np.pi,length)
xgate_phi = np.linspace(phi,phi,length)

# this array contains all the coordinates in each phase
xgate= []
# these array contains only one kind of coordinates
xgate_x = []
xgate_y = []
xgate_z = []

for i in range(length):
    # X means x coordinate in the initial phase
    xgate_x.append(X)
    xgate_z.append(np.cos(xgate_theta[i]))
    xgate_y.append(np.sqrt(1-np.sqrt(xgate_x[i]**2+xgate_z[i]**2))*(-1))
for j in range(length):             xgate.append(put.quiver(0,0,0,xgate_x[j],xgate_y[j],xgate_z[j],color="red")

# I don't show you the codes for fig, but it doesn't have any problems
ani = animation.ArtistAnimation(fig,xgate,interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

Every time I see the result, I only get the image below.
[image: The image that I want to make it an animation]

I would appreciate if anyone tell me how to change it into an animation.

Comment: Are you using `matplotlib`?

Comment: (Assuming you're using `matplotlib`) there is a `save() `method (https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.ArtistAnimation.save)

Comment: Also your code in the question is incomplete and contains error. e.g. what are `theta`, `pi` and `X`?

Comment: Also the object "put" is not defined in this code sample.  One obvious point though - your xgate list should be populated with call for plt.imshow(), with the kwarg animated=True in each one.

Comment: @Anthony Kong  Yes, I'm using matplotlib module and I've tried saving the animation, but what I got was the image above.

Comment: @Anthony Kong  As I mentioned, theta and phi are inputs from users, X is the x coordinate in the initial phase.

Comment: @AlecZ How can I use plt.imshow() to make it an animation?  I googled its function, but it just shows an image, not an animation.  Will you elaborate your suggestion, please?

Comment: @MakotoNakai good example here:  https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/dynamic_image.html#sphx-glr-gallery-animation-dynamic-image-py